# Play full screen video in texture view in android

Tags: android

I want to play video in full screen.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:rotation="270"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code:

@Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
         Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

```
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);

            // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

output:
[image]

How to display full screen video.

Please help me.